# XLPagerTabStrip: How to change indicator action

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I am using `BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController<MyCell>` in `XLPagerTabStrip`, and have three child view controllers:

- `FirstViewController` with `IndicatorInfo first`
- `SecondViewController` with `IndicatorInfo second`
- `ThirdViewController` with `IndicatorInfo third`

My question is can I do something like this:

When my current view controller is `FirstViewController`, `IndicatorInfo first` and `IndicatorInfo second` is disable (can't be selected), and select `IndicatorInfo third` will jump to `SecondViewController`, but when current view controller is `SecondViewController`, `IndicatorInfo second` is disable, `IndicatorInfo first` and `IndicatorInfo third` works originally, and when my current view controller is `ThirdViewController`, `IndicatorInfo second` and `IndicatorInfo third` is disable, select `IndicatorInfo first` will jump to `SecondViewController`, is this possible?

Sorry for my bad explanation, and I also not sure is that called `IndicatorInfo` or `Tab` or something else, so if you have any problem just let me know.

Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE:
I tried to make a prototype to show what I want to do, here is the [link](https://pr.to/C1UN1R/).

Comment: What is your exact problem...?

Comment: @MohammedHussain my problem is when I am in different current view controller, I want the indicator's action changed.

Comment: Indicator means slider right?

Comment: @MohammedHussain hmm...maybe I should just called it button

Comment: Can you share a screen shot what you actually want

Comment: @MohammedHussain I just update a link to show what I want.